# Split total by percentage and receive the same result

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is a little bit complicated to describe, but I will try my best. I have a total, let's say `1000`. Then I want to split it by percentages, position count is all the time different. So there can be 3 or 70 or 130 positions or whatever. Then split sum should correspond to target value.

Here is an example of the case:

1. I input names under Customer request
2. I enter percentage for position under Percentage

In amount calculation I use `=CEILING($C$5*C10;10)` and in all the rest of the cells the same to get numbers look nice. It is working fine but he problem is that now totals does not match. It should end up in `15550` but after calculating totals after split it is `15660`.

Is there any ideas what kind of master artificial intelligent formula can do the trick to produce nice looking numbers, taking in consideration to match `Total (target)` in the end if `Total (calculated)` percentage is 100%?

P.S. Any ideas are welcomed as well. The target is to have nice looking, rounded numbers that will sum in the same number as target - total.

Comment: If you rounding numbers, then it is expected that sum will be different from target amount. And summing them makes no sense at all.

Comment: I understand that, but I am seeking in solution that will round numbers and end up in the same total.

Comment: Make one of them the difference between 100 and the sum of the others? But I agree with Michal.

Comment: They does need to be necessary %, any other solution will work. I am just wondering what can be the solution.

Comment: You can store real values in hidden columns and sum them instead.

Comment: How do you calculate the right % of each position? You said *So there can be 3 or 70 or 130 positions or whatever* so how do you choose which % fits better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `CEILING`, your output number (e.g. 15660) is guaranteed to be greater than or equal to your input number (e.g. 15550). This is because any time a "perfect match" isn't found, it rounds up.

My first suggestion is to instead use `ROUND` instead of `CEILING`. Right off the bat this will perform better than `CEILING` because `ROUND` can round up or down but `CEILING` can only round up.

E.g. try this:

```
= ROUND($C$5*C10,-1)
```

Since you provide no details as to "how" the data needs to be adjusted to meet your input value, I can't really provide any automatic solution.

One manual solution is that you can make a new column which indicates whether the data was rounded up or rounded down, and you can adjust the percentages manually to get the data you're looking for.

Here's a formula to tell you if the data is rounded up or down (e.g. put formula in cell `E10` and drag down):

```
= CHOOSE(SIGN(D10-($C$5*C10))+2,"Round Down","Perfect Match","Round Up")
```

You can use this information to manually tweak your percentages. For example... if your output value is too high, you can slightly decrease some of the higher percentages that "Round Up" and slightly increase some of the lower percentages (e.g. if you have 10% and 3%, maybe change them to 10.1% and 2.9% to see if that makes a difference.)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to this. I came up with a simple method of doing it. First is to calculate your percentage rounding down. That is the minimum share per customer. Then take the the exact share, without rounding, and subtract the minimum share from that. this is the additional share to meet the percentage. Then you can use the LARGE function to find the n largest values of the additional share. The n will be the sum of all your additional share divided by your multiple. If the remaining is >= to the result of the LARGE function, you can award an additional share, otherwise return 0.

```
[MINIMUM SHARE]           =FLOOR.MATH([PERCENTAGE]*[TOTAL],[MULTIPLE])
[REMAINING]               =([PERCENTAGE]*[TOTAL])-[MINIMUM SHARE]
[TOTAL ADDITIONAL SHARE]  =[TOTAL]-SUM([MINIMUM SHARE RANGE])
[ADDITIONAL SHARE         =IF([REMAINING]>=LARGE([REMAINING RANGE],[ADDITIONAL SHARE NEEDED / [MULTIPLE]),[MULTIPLE],0)
```

[Example spreadsheet image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziBIZ.png)